# Rails application's public folder return empty response body

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded an open source Rails application and deployed it on my server. But I found that the assets which have been compiled can't be accessed. It return an empty response with code 200.

So I create a file called `test.html`, and access it, it returns an empty response with code 200, too. And if I access a file which doesn't exist, then it returns a rails 404 error.

What's the problem? I have tried unicorn and thin, the result is the same.

Comment: Are you sure the response is empty?

Comment: Yes, I test it in chrome and the length of the response is zero.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: could it be that your public folder doesn't have the read permission. Try chmod -R 777 public

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel The open source project is https://github.com/ruby-china/ruby-china, and I deploy it in http://sjyyt.com:3000, you can find the page is ugly because its assets return empty response.

Comment: @charlysisto, I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: I see but this css is ok http://sjyyt.com:3000/assets/home.css, so I guess manifest file is broken. Are you running the app in production env? Can you try running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` on the server?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: Yes, I am running the app in production env, and everything goes well in development env, so you can access the normal css path. But when it goes to the public folder, the response is just empty. So I have tried precompile the assets again. And as expected, it doesn't work. So my question is: why the public folder return empty response with code 200???